# How to examine problems with the blocked call to write() on Linux/FreeBSD?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, tcp, bsd

I have an active running process on Linux/FreeBSD. I have traced it, and found that one of the threads is blocked on the call to the function `write()` - as an argument it has a TCP socket. It's may be hanging for hours.

What are the ways to examine the reasons behind the blocked `write()`? What are the potential problems?

*P.S. System utilities are appreciated.*

Comment: Your server is stuft?  That, or protocol problems.

Comment: @MartinJames What is "stuft"? What kind of problems can I experience, while using the raw tcp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current case there was the following problem. The DNS resolution gave me some IP-address, that was far-far away, or even unreachable. The `write()` was hanging because no TCP response was ever received from that host.

The problem is solved by setting timeout on send operations via `setsockopt` and `SO_SNDTIMEO`.